# I want to fix the place on screen where Java Program launches

Tags: java

I am developing a Java Desktop application.

Whenever I launch a Java app from command prompt It launches from Left Top corner of the windows screen.

I want to determine like to launch the application from center of the screen like.

How to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Swing, on your `JFrame` containing your code use

Note that this will also work on anything else extending from `java.awt.Window`

```
JFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

This will set your `JFrame` relative to nothing, and it appears in the center of the main monitor

Check the documentation on `java.awt.Window` [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html)

Comment: Or you could JFrame.setLocation( x, y); where x & y are int's.  This will set the location to x across and y down from the top left corner.

Comment: @cliff2310 Bit more imprecise to find the size of the monitor, the size of the window, the size of the window decorations (the border on Windows + toolbar at the top of the window), and then attempting to calculate the correct topleft X/Y coordinates to set the window to

Comment: All true. Just giving an alternate way of setting the position of the JFrame.